# Problems with a tile worldscreen system?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, tile

Im trying to make a tile based world screen for my game , here are the three classes i have

```
namespace WindowsGame1
{
 public enum Tiletype
{Grass,
    Water,
    Foothill,
    Mountain

}
public struct Tile
{
    public  Tiletype TerrainType { get; set; }
    public Texture2D TileGFX { get; set; }
    public Rectangle SrcRect { get; set; }
    public Vector2 Location { get; set; }
    public int AniFrame { get; set; }

    // TILE ACTIONS
    public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
    public bool IsTouchTrigger { get; set; }
    public bool IsStepTrigger { get; set; }
}
}
```

MapBase class

```
    public class MapBase
{

    public Tile[,] TileList = new Tile[1, 1];
    public MapBase(int width, int height, Vector2 start)
    {
        TileList = new Tile[width + 1, height + 1];

        // TEMPORARY MAP
        for (int X = 0; X <= width; X++)
        {
            for (int Y = 0; Y <= height; Y++)
            {
                TileList[X, Y] = new Tile();
                var _with1 = TileList[X, Y];
                _with1.TerrainType = Tiletype.Water;
                _with1.TileGFX = Textures.World;
                _with1.AniFrame = 0;
                _with1.IsBlocked = true;
            }
        }

        // SIMPLE ISLAND
        for (int z = 22; z <= 33; z++)
        {
            for (int c = 22; c <= 31; c++)
            {
                TileList[z, c].TerrainType = Tiletype.Grass;
            }
        }

        TileList[27, 25].TerrainType = Tiletype.Foothill;
        TileList[28, 25].TerrainType = Tiletype.Foothill;
        TileList[27, 24].TerrainType = Tiletype.Foothill;
        TileList[28, 26].TerrainType = Tiletype.Mountain;


        for (int x = 0; x <= width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= height; y++)
            {
                TileList[x, y].SrcRect = GetTileSource(TileList[x, y].TerrainType);
            }
        }

    }
```

GetTitleSource function

```
    private Rectangle GetTileSource(Tiletype TType)
    {
        Rectangle sRect = default(Rectangle);
        switch (TType)
        {
            case Tiletype.Grass:
                sRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16);
                break;
            case Tiletype.Water:
                sRect = new Rectangle(0, 80, 16, 16);
                break;
            case Tiletype.Foothill:
                sRect = new Rectangle(48, 0, 16, 16);
                break;
            case Tiletype.Mountain:
                sRect = new Rectangle(32, 0, 16, 16);
                break;
        }
        return sRect;
    }
}
```

Class WorldScreen

```
 class Worldscreen : BaseScreen
{
    public int MapWidth = 100;
    public int MapHeight = 100;
    public int TileSize = 32;
    public int MapX = 20;
    public int MapY = 19;
    public MapBase Map = new MapBase(100, 100, new Vector2(0, 0));

    public Worldscreen(GraphicsDevice device)
        : base(device, "WorldScreen")
    {
        Map = new MapBase(MapWidth, MapHeight, new Vector2(0, 0));
    }
```

Draw function

```
    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Draw(gameTime);
        Globals.spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone);

        //DRAW TILE LAYER
        for (int DrawX = -1; DrawX <= 16; DrawX++)
        {
            for (int DrawY = -1; DrawY <= 15; DrawY++)
            {
                int x = DrawX + MapX;
                int y = DrawY + MapY;

                if (x > 0 & x <= MapWidth & y >= 0 & y <= MapHeight)
                {
                    Globals.spriteBatch.Draw(Map.TileList[x,y].TileGFX, new Rectangle(DrawX * TileSize, DrawY * TileSize, TileSize, TileSize), Map.TileList[x, y].SrcRect, Color.White);
                    // VIEW COORDINATES ON TILE
                    //Globals.SpriteBatch.DrawString(Fonts.Arial_8, "X:" & x & vbCrLf & "Y:" & y, New Vector2(DrawX * TileSize, DrawY * TileSize), Color.Black)
                }
            }
        }
        Globals.spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```

When I try to run the draw void it comes up with this error on the world screen class
This method does not accept null for this parameter.
Parameter name: texture

is there any way to solve this or do i have to rework these classes.

Answer (score 0):

you got all the info you need to debug this yourself :

theres a method on the world screen class who have a texture = null.

Go step-by-step debug and find out which one, unless its a simple error we can find looking at your code, but its often not that easy. ( ex : do you have a list which isnt instanciate ?  )

but since its a method paramaters ... the only method that accept a texture as a parameter is GetTileSource.

So quickly what could explain it ... I'd check 2 things :

A- are you sure your loop have correct bound ? You might simply be asking for a tile in that array that doesn't exist since its out of bound. (array are 0 base, and you loop up to <= height instead of < height)

B- 2nd thing i'd check would be (since this is a texture ) that you didn't load one of those texture you use ...